# How to enable onboard in lightdm-gtk-greeter?

Tags: lightdm, onboard

Unity-greeter crashes, and constantly respawns, not letting me in. So, I configured auto login but that won't start anything except Unity session. I changed the `lightdm.conf` file to run Xubuntu but Unity still shows up. If I create a new user, it will start in Xubuntu just fine. I deleted my .conf XFCE prefs and that fixed nothing.

I can at least get in to the gtk login greeter but then the onboard keyboard does not show up. If I could get the onboard keyboard in the gtk greeter, I would be super happy. The onboard keyboard shows up in the Unity greeter just fine. But not the gtk greeter.

I don't have a solid keyboard because it is a tablet. So, I need the onboard in the greeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There still seems like there is no way to get an on screen keyboard in the gtk greeter. 
Enabling the onscreen keyboard in the unity-greeter is somewhat easy but after a lot of research it appears that no one has done the development necessary to start an onscreen keyboard in the gtk greeter.

My particular problem however, does have a hack/fix. That is, I switched on "user does not need password on login"

This feature makes it so when the gtk greeter comes up, I only need to click on my user name to login. My user still has a password which I can use for package management etc. But for simply logging in , turning off the need to enter a password gives me at least a temporary fix...

I can at least get into my system without a keyboard.

Comment: I suppose this is not possible, if you have encrypted home folder.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open "dconf Editor" program.
2. From tree in left panel open com/canonical/unity-greater
3. Chek onscreen-keyboard ckeckbox from right panel.

Have a nice time.

Comment: that's for the unity greeter right? I need to enable it for the gtk greeter

Comment: not working on 16.04 unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

With newer versions of lightdm (1.5.1?) there is a commented out line in the `lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` file. The option at login is shown if you insert `keyboard=whatever_to_start`.

Example for onboard:

```
[greeter]

keyboard=onboard
```

see patch: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm-gtk-greeter/+bug/905809

Comment: And you can toggle on-screen keyboard by F3 or in the accessibility menu.

Comment: Sometimes, when you want an on-screen keyboard, it's because you physically don't have a keyboard. Therefore pressing F3 may not be possible